# How is infinite variance reflected in the graph?

Tags: probability, statistics, infinity, variance, density-function

The density function: $$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
            x & \text{if } 0 < x \leq 1\\
      x^{-3} & \text{if } x>1\\
            0 & \text{otherwise} \\
       \end{cases}
$$
Has finite mean ($4/3$) and infinite variance - the integral diverges logarithmically: one ends with a tail for $E(X^2)$ which involves $\int_1^\infty \frac 1 x \, dx$. 
I am trying to solve the problem where I should comment on the figure involving the density function and simulated values from it and the relation to the calculation of $E(X^2)$. It looks like this in R:
[Histogram and density function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYvD8.jpg)

I have no clue how the infinite variance is reflected in the figure...Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Are you sure that this is density finction? It seems to me its integral is less than 1.

Comment: The integral of g(x) from 0 to 1 is 0.5 and so it the integral from 1 to infinity. So I think that it is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake,

Comment: Why are you calling this a "distribution function"? Conventionally that means it's the cumulative distribution function, but certainly that is not what it is.

Comment: Thx for the correction. I have changed the name to density function.